# Sequelize seems to cap at 30 models

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I'm having an issue where in my models/index.js Sequelize file (the file that initializes the Sequelize/db models) seems to cap at 30 models.

I don't know why this is, I can't find any documentation on it.

When initializing the Express server with more than 30 models, the 31st model gives the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/{model-name}'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: To my knowledge there is no limit on sequelize models, I have a system with more than 80 that initialise on start up. Can you expand on what your index.js file is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

./modelName instead of /modelName